# ASPxGridview Custom Sorting?? by Month Name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an aspxgridview which groups first by year and then by month. Basically my query returns Month and year as seperate columns. Now if I return month as "January or February" then ASPxGridview does not know how to sort this.

I heard of custom sorting, but even then if I return month column as a number and use dataitem template to convert it to a name...it works but then when exporting it only exports the number not the dataitemtemplate.

I am really confused, can anyone help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, the ASPxGridViewExporter cannot export data shown in a template container.  This is because a developer can show any control inside it and we cannot determine which data is shown there.  So, if you need to show a custom text when this column data is exported, use the ASPxGridViewExporter's [RenderBrick](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewExportASPxGridViewExporter_RenderBricktopic) event.  However, the better solution is to create an unbound column and pass data to this column cells using the ASPxGridView's [CustomUnboundColumnData](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event handler.  In this case, you should refuse from using DataItemTemplate.